# Graph returned an error: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using Facebook API code to publish a post on pages. But occurred the error.

 I've uploaded the code on my domain even I am getting this problem.

> Graph returned an error: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the
>   application to perform this action

FB API Code:

```
  <?php 
    require_once(__DIR__."/fb-sdk/src/Facebook/autoload.php");

    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
       'app_id' => 'MY_APP_ID',
       'app_secret' => 'MY_SECRET',
       'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
    ]);
    $linkData = [
       'link' => 'www.mywebsite.com',
       'message' => 'Testing API'
    ];
    $pageAccessToken ='MY_ACCESS_TOKEN';
    try {
       $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $linkData, $pageAccessToken);
    } 
    catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
       echo 'Graph returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
       exit;
    }
    catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
       echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
       exit;
    }
    $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
 ?>
```

You can see the advance setting of API in the image, is there anything missing in code or settings?
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can Follow this tutorial

http://www.discussdesk.com/post-into-facebook-page-using-graph-api-with-php.htm

To post to a Page "as Page", you need to authorize the user with "publish_pages" and you need to use a Page Token. Try to add publish_pages to your permission list:

```
$config['facebook']['permissions'] = array(
  'email',
  'user_location',
  'user_birthday',
  'publish_actions',
  'publish_pages',
  'manage_pages',
  'public_profile',
);
```